# Using LINQ to get the results from another LINQ collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ statement which pulls the top N record IDs from a collection and then another query which pulls all records which have those IDs. It feels very clunky and inefficient and i was wondering if there might be a more succinct, LINQy way to get the same results

```
var records = cache.Select(rec => rec.Id).Distinct().Take(n);

var results = cache.Where(rec => records.Contains(rec.Id));
```

FYI - there will be multiple records with the same ID, which is why there is the Distinct() and why i can't use a simple Take() in the first place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var results = cache.GroupBy(rec => rec.Id, rec => rec)
                   .Take(n)
                   .SelectMany(rec => rec);
```

Comment: This is great. Works. LINQy. Probably not going to be any faster than your original, may be slower depending on what happens with the GroupBy.

Comment: It will always be a bit slower than the original because it has to make a full pass the first time; original can stop when it hits *n* elements.  Probably not a major issue if the list is small.

Comment: @Aaronaught: But the original has to do a full pass in the second query, *and* perform a `Contains` lookup at each step. That could potentially be a real performance killer. Of course, the only way to know for sure is to benchmark with real-world data.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing you did, but in one line and with Join() instead of Contains():

```
var results = cache
    .Select(rec => rec.Id)
    .Distinct()
    .Take(n)
    .ToList()
    .Join(cache, rec => rec, record => record.Id, (rec, record) => record);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortuately LINQ doesn't natively support letting the user choose a member to get distinct records on. So I recommend creating your own extension method for it:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Returns a list with the ability to specify key(s) to compare uniqueness on
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Source type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">Source</param>
    /// <param name="keyPredicate">Predicate with key(s) to perform comparison on</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                             Func<T, object> keyPredicate)
    {
        return source.Distinct(new GenericComparer<T>(keyPredicate));
    }
```

And then create a generic comparer, which you will notice is quite generic.

```
   public class GenericComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        private Func<T, object> _uniqueCheckerMethod;

        public GenericComparer(Func<T, object> keyPredicate)
        {
            _uniqueCheckerMethod = keyPredicate;
        }

        #region IEqualityComparer<T> Members

        bool IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return _uniqueCheckerMethod(x).Equals(_uniqueCheckerMethod(y));
        }

        int IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return _uniqueCheckerMethod(obj).GetHashCode();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Now just chain up your LINQ statement:
var records = cache.Select(rec => rec.Id).Distinct().Take(n);

```
var results = cache.Distinct(rec => rec.Id).Take(n));
```

hth

Comment: I don't think this will give you the same results.  
This seems to me like it would give you n results only - the first item with each distinct ID, rather than all of the items matching the first n IDs (i.e. possibly more than n)

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think of doing this in SQL would be with a subquery, so probably there are going to be two LINQ queries also...
It "feels" inefficient... is it? Maybe you are worrying about something that is not worth worrying about. You can probly make it into one line by doing a join, but whether that is clearer / better / more efficient is a different question.

Edit: The extension method answer by Aaronaught can be made to work like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeByDistinctKey<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keyFunc, int numKeys) {
    if(keyFunc == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("keyFunc");
    }

    List<TKey> keys = new List<TKey>();
    foreach(T item in source) {
        TKey key = keyFunc(item);
        if(keys.Contains(key)) {
            // one if the first n keys, yield
            yield return item;
        } else if(keys.Count < numKeys) {
            // new key, but still one of the first n seen, yield
            keys.Add(key);
            yield return item;
        }
        // have enough distinct keys, just keep going to return all of the items with those keys
    }
}
```

However, the GroupBy / SelectMany looks the neatest. I would go with that one.

Comment: Your extension method will be more efficient if you use `HashSet<T>` rather than `List<T>` for the keys collection. The `Contains` lookups should be close to O(1) for `HashSet<T>`, compared to O(n) for `List<T>`.

Comment: I haven't tested the efficiency but the "Contains" lookup in the second statement seems like it could be a bottleneck. That's what was sticking out for me. Mostly though i just knew there would be better ways to do the same thing and was curious what people would have to say. I had no idea i'd get so many good ideas! :-)

Comment: Totally, thanks. I tend to go with simple first then optimise later, but for this type of thing (totally set operations only) one should probably use Set types from the get go.
Thanks

Comment: I would really like to see the comparison of the GroupBy+SelectMany to something like this HashSet+Contains+Enumeration method. And also Aaron's one which may be faster if you can gaurantee a sorted list (if the fixes the remaining bug :D )

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in "Linqy" way (you could group, but it would be pretty inefficient), but that doesn't mean you can't make your own way:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeDistinctByKey<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TKey> keyFunc,
    int count)
{
    if (keyFunc == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("keyFunc");
    if (count <= 0)
        yield break;

    int currentCount = 0;
    TKey lastKey = default(TKey);
    bool isFirst = true;
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
        TKey key = keyFunc(item);
        if (!isFirst && (key != lastKey))
            currentCount++;
        if (currentCount > count)
            yield break;
        isFirst = false;
        lastKey = key;
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke it with this:

```
var items = cache.TakeDistinctByKey(rec => rec.Id, 20);
```

If you have composite keys or anything like that you could easily extend the method above to take an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` as an argument.

Also note that this depends on the elements being in sorted order by key.  If they aren't, you could either change the algorithm above to use a `HashSet<TKey>` instead of a straight count and last-item comparison, or invoke it with this instead:

```
var items = cache.OrderBy(rec => rec.Id).TakeDistinctByKey(rec => rec.Id, 20);
```

Edit - I'd also like to point out that in SQL I would either use a `ROW_NUMBER` query or a recursive CTE, depending on the performance requirement - a distinct+join is *not* the most efficient method.  If your cache is in sorted order (or if you can change it to be in sorted order) then the method above will be by far the cheapest in terms of both memory and execution time.

Comment: I think this is close, but won't this give the first (up to) n items with first key found? I feel that this is close though, just need to change it to keep a list of the keys as they are encountered, and only add new keys to that list until there are n keys in the list. Keep going through the whole list yielding items that match the keys (or that are a new key up to n, as mentioned). P.S. I think  your way of doing it is good otherwise :)

Comment: @David - not quite sure what you mean - unless there's a bug, this extension should return all items in the source with the first N distinct keys (as long as it's in sorted order, otherwise it's an O(N) operation and you need a hash set, in which case maybe I'd just go with the `GroupBy`/`SelectMany` answer).  I think that's what the OP wanted... did I mis-read the question?

Comment: Yes. I don't think that is what they wanted. Your code will only work on a pre-sorted list, it will get all of the first id, skip the first item with the second id, and then only return max n items rather than all of the items with the first n IDs... unless I am misundertanding the OP.

Comment: Sorry, correction - " and then only return max n items" is not right, you will just skip the first item with each id.

Comment: @David: You're right, I see it now - corrected, thanks for the catch.